# Webapi programming pause or sleep

Tags: javascript

Please bare in mind I am very inexperienced in programming and my skills and knowledge are limited.

I am trying to create a line of code the will operate a lighting controller via a network or Web portal.  I can create a command to 'fire' a programe and one to 'kill' the programe.   What I need to do is in one line of code is to fire the programe pause for an alloted period (ms or sec) and then kill the programe.

Not even sure if what I need is possible, can anyone Help?

These are the two lines of code that do the individual tasks:

http://10.10.4.106:4430/titan/script/Playbacks/FirePlaybackAtLevel?userNumber=18&level=1&bool=false

http://10.10.4.106:4430/titan/script/Playbacks/KillPlayback?userNumber=18

Comment: You can use [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) so you're code will call the `on();` and then `setTimeout(off,3000)`

Comment: `a line of code the will operate a lighting controller via a network or Web portal` - a single line of code to do that? I take it what you do know about programming comes from "Hollywood" :p

Comment: The line of code currently fires one operation to the lighting controller I wish it to do two, as I said I'm not even sure if it's possible but I am told it is.  Hollywood has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a **setTimeout** that waits (ms) to run a javascript code.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // rest of code here
}, 2000);
```